# How does wifi hotspot internally works ?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, wifi-tethering

I have an Android device which has Access Point (Wifi Tethering). What exactly happens when another device connects to this access point ? 
Which are the classes or libraries (if any) involved in whole process ?

P.S - I have searched for answers on internet but no success so far. 
TIA

Comment: Is this purely for educational purposes, or is there a problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: this is for educational purpose. Just eager to know the internal workings of wifi hotspot. 
There is no documentation available for this and hence I did shot my question here :)

Comment: This site is not really suited for such questions, since it's tailored to [solving problems related to using Android devices](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).  I would recommend stackoverflow.com instead.

Comment: android.stackexchange.com says "Android Enthusiasts", so I guess its fine to ask this question here. Stackoverflow is for solving "code" related issues.  Pardon me if I am wrong. 

Can you please help me with the answer of my question ?

Comment: If you still feel that this question does not fit here, please let me know, I will delete it. :)